# Using function of an object after grabbing it from array

Tags: javascript

When I try to grab the object from the array, the type is undefined. Therefore I cannot use a method from the undefined object as it doesn't exist. I am relatively new to JavaScript and I have come straight from Java so the way of retrieving objects is kind of new to me. This is what I currently have.

```
var fleetAmount = 0;
var fleets = [];
function Fleet(number) {
    this.number = number;
    this.activities = [];
    this.addActivity = function (activity) {
        this.activities.push(activity);
    };
    fleets.push(this);
}
var getFleet = function(fleetNumber) {
    return fleets[fleetAmount - fleetNumber];
}
```

This is where I try to grab the object and preform the function

```
const Fl = require(‘fleet.js’);
const fleet = Fl.getFleet(fleetNumber);
fleet.addActivity(activity);
```

I am also working in Node.js, which is how I am using the require method.

Comment: `getFleet` is a standalone variable, not a property of the `Fleet` function, so `Fleet.getFleet` will not work

Answer (score 0):

you want to create a new fleet object and add it, not "this"..
adding "this" would cause a circular reference, where
`this.fleets[i] = this` (and all fleets would have the same value)

when calling get fleet, I would check that a fleet was returned from get fleet
in case amount is less than the number you send to getFleet (where according to what you posted: 1 returns the last, 2 returns second to last etc..)..

I hope this explanation makes sense.. anyways, this should work..

```js
var fleets = [];
doStuff();

function doStuff(){
  addFleet(1);
  addFleet(2);
  addFleet(7);  
  addFleet(3);  

  // should return null
  let fleet1 = getFleetByNumber(5); 

  // should return the fleet with number 7, and not change the fleet with number 1
  let fleet2 = getFleetByNumber(7); 
  if(fleet2){
      fleet2.addActivity("activity");
  }

  console.log(`fleets: ${JSON.stringify(fleets)} \nfleet1: ${JSON.stringify(fleet1)} \nfleet2: ${JSON.stringify(fleet2)}`);
}

function addFleet(number) {
  let fleet = { number: number,
                      activities: [] };
  fleet.addActivity = function (activity) {
      this.activities.push(activity);
  };
  fleets.push(fleet);
}

function getFleetByNumber(fleetNumber) {
    return fleets.find(function (e) {
        return e.number == fleetNumber;
    });
}

function getFleet(fleetNumber) {
  let result = null;
  if(fleets.length - fleetNumber >= 0){
      result = fleets[fleets.length - fleetNumber];
  }
  return result; 
}
```

Comment: I tried this code and I am still getting the same problem as before. I printed the getFleet(1) to console and it returned "undefined". I printed the array and it returns as this `[ { number: 1, activities: [], addActivity: [Function (anonymous)] } ]` This is essentially what what happening before but in a different format. I am still getting the "Cannot read property 'addActivity' of undefined" error in console.
@audzzy

Comment: I edited this to have the logic you seemed to want.. I noticed a problem with the code you posted that worked for you (getFleet changed the value of the returned fleet) so please have a look at this now..

Answer (score 0):

In combination with the answer from @audzzy I changed the getFleet() function so that it would be more efficient. I tested it out and it worked. This is what I used

```html
    function getFleet(fleetNumber) {
        let result = fleets.filter(function (e) {
            return e.number = fleetNumber;
        })
        return result[0];
    }
```

Thanks for the help! I appreciate it.

Comment: the code you run here changes the value of the array, so if I called getFleet(5) and have what you posted [ { number: 1, activities: [], addActivity: [Function (anonymous)] } ] it would change the value of number to 5 and return it.. I tweaked my code to have your logic as well (getFleetByFleetNumber) and add a validation to make sure that we got something from the function before calling addActivity