# Stop objects from sharing values

Tags: javascript, discord.js

To set this up I create 2 fleet objects, store them in an array, then print the array to console. This is what I get after both fleet objects are created.

```
[
  { number: 1, activities: [], addActivity: [Function (anonymous)] },
  { number: 2, activities: [], addActivity: [Function (anonymous)] } 
]
```

The addActivity function of the fleet object adds an activity to the activities array of the specified object. This is the function.

```
    fleet.addActivity = function(activity) {
        this.activities.push(activity);
    }
```

However, whenever I use this function, it changes both fleet objects in the array so that they have the same number as the one that I specified. For example,

```
const fleet = Fleet.getFleet(1);
fleet.addActivity('Run');
```

This is printed in console:

```
[
  {
    number: 1,
    activities: [ 'Run' ],
    addActivity: [Function (anonymous)]
  },
  { number: 1, activities: [], addActivity: [Function (anonymous)] }
]
```

If I were to do it again using

```
const fleet = Fleet.getFleet(2);
fleet.addActivity('Walk');
```

Console would print:

```
[
  {
    number: 2,
    activities: [ 'Walk', 'Run' ],
    addActivity: [Function (anonymous)]
  },
  { number: 2, activities: [], addActivity: [Function (anonymous)] }
]
```

Does anyone have any idea of how to fix this?

EDIT- Here is the getFleet function:

```
function getFleet(fleetNumber) {
    let result = exports.fleets.filter(function (e) {
        return e.number = fleetNumber;
    });
    return result[0];
}
```

I also tried the lodash deep cloning method and I still have the same issue. This is what my addFleet function currently looks. My previous method of creating fleets has been commented out.

```
function addFleet(number) {
    /*let fleet = {
        number: number,
        activities: []
    };
    fleet.addActivity = function(activity) {
        this.activities.push(activity);
    }*/
    const deepClone = lodash.cloneDeep(originalFleet);
    deepClone.number = number;
    exports.fleets.push(deepClone);
    exports.fleetAmount += 1;
    exports.currentFleets.push(number);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: Please show the `getFleet` function.

Comment: Please take a look at the question you posted yesterday, as I regarded this issue when you posted your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64309315/using-function-of-an-object-after-grabbing-it-from-array/64309691?noredirect=1#comment113719317_64309691

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is inside your `getFleet()` function. Instead of checking each object number for equality, you're actually overwriting the variable. The fix is as simple as changing one equal sign to three.

```js
function getFleet(fleetNumber) {
    let result = exports.fleets.filter(function (e) {
        return e.number === fleetNumber; // check for equality instead of overwriting
    });
    return result[0];
}
```

Also, you're overcomplicating the function. Since you only need to find the first match, you should use `Array.prototype.find()`

```js
function getFleet(fleetNumber) {
  return exports.fleets.find((e) => e.number === fleetNumber)
}
```